# Ajax Autocomplete code not working(with database)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have wriiten a simple ajax autocomplete code in Asp.net ( C#)

This is the code

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" TargetControlID="TextBox1" UseContextKey="True"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Station"].ToString();
string selectString = "SELECT *from Station";

List<String> CustList = new List<string>(count);
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    sqlConn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(selectString, sqlConn))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
            CustList.Add(reader["DBRT"].ToString());//DBRT is the Column name

    }
}
return (CustList.ToArray());
```

When i execute and run the program nothing happens. I dont know what has went wrong. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code in the return part

```
return Custlist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these two attributes on the method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList................{}
```

EDIT: Couple of things I noticed in your code:
`string selectString = "SELECT *from Station";` is wrong, it should be `SELECT * from` (A space between * and from is missing).

Also you need to Select only those names which starts with the prefix string value your method is receiving. Your method signature should be:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]  
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey) {
```

Where prefixText is what you suppose to look in the database. Your select query should be:

```
string selectString = "SELECT * from Station where @Name like";
```

and then after defining the command use: 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(NAME, prefixText + "%");

This will select the values from the table based on the typed in values from the textbox. 
Its similar to:
`Select * from station where Name like 'some%';`

Also, I would suggest you to limit your result with [Top](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/02/sql-server-how-to-retrieve-top-and-bottom-rows-together-using-t-sql/) keyword, because the table may contain too many rows and your AutoComplete extender will not perform as desired.

Comment: I have these two    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]

Comment: @user1465978, what is the error you are getting , and put a break point and see if you are getting anything in the list from the database

Comment: It is giving and error saying
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at   
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Station"].ToString();

Comment: @user1465978, look in the web config and see if you have a connection named "Station" , that is missing in your web config or it has a different name

Comment: Thank uu ...it was not there previously but now i have added but now when i execute i can enter only two letter from the third letter it is getting stuck